# start a new R session in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

How can I start a new `R` session in `knitr`? I would rather start a new session rather than use something like `rm(list=ls())` because it is not equivalent.

```
<<myname>>=
#some R code
@
<<another_chunk>>=
#start a new R session
#more R code
@
```

Comment: maybe `zap()` from the `epicalc` library can help you. Could you specify what you would like to _obtain_ by restarting R?

Comment: @EricD.Brean fair question. I really don't know enough about `R`, but I have very long programs that I'm worried leave a lot of stuff (environments, objects, etc.) around. `zap` is interesting but I would feel much safer having a clean `R` session.

Comment: so, you don't have a specific problem, but you are _worried R will leave a lot of stuff around_? I can see how you might have this _worry_ coming from a windows background, but I don't think you need to worry about that. Regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, now I have something more substantial for you, inspired by [an answer on the R-help list by Georg Ruß](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Reset-R-to-a-vanilla-state-td3090927.html). He suggest three things to get R back to how it was at start up, I've written this six step manual for you.

First, you save a string of the packages you have running at start up (this should be done before anything else, before you run any other code),

```
foo <- .packages()
```

Second, when you want to reset R, as you also mention, you run

```
rm(list=ls())
```

to remove all objects. Then, third, you run,

```
bar <- .packages()
```

to get a string of current packages. Followed by,

```
foobar <- setdiff(bar, foo)
```

Fifth, you remove the difference with this work-around loop,

```
toRemove <- paste("package:", foobar, sep='') 
#or paste0("package:", foobar) in R-2.15.0 or higher
for(i in seq_along(foobar)) {           
    detach(toRemove[i], character.only=TRUE)    
}
```

Sixth, depending on your setup, you source your .Rprofile

```
source(".Rprofile")
```

This should put R into the state it was in when you started it. I could have overlooked something.

Comment: Thank you, I will post back if I find that something else needs to be changed.

Comment: @RichieCotten, I placed it there not to leave the `toRemove` in the environment. Do you think it's slow down the loop significantly?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of starting a new R session in `knitr`, I would recommend you just to start a new R session in your terminal (or command window) like this:

```
R -e "library(knitr); knit('your_input.Rnw')"
```

If you are under Windows, you have to put the bin directory of R into your environment variable `PATH` (I'm very tired of describing how to do this, so google it by yourself if you are in the Windows world, or see the [LyX Sweave manual](https://github.com/downloads/yihui/lyx/sweave.pdf)).

However, most editors do start a new R session when calling Sweave or `knitr`, e.g. LyX and RStudio, etc. You can find more possible editors in http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/ I do not really see the need to call `R -e ...` in the terminal.

Comment: thank you for this option. I am using Ubuntu so `PATH` is not a problem.

Comment: I am still having a problem. I need to start a new R session *within* knitr. I have tried q() to reset but that does not work. A problem is that I source .R files in my .tex file (no fancy editor) in a knitr chunk as follows: `source('file1.R')` and then the next line `source('file2.R')` but really I want those to be run in different R sessions where I think they are run in the same. Putting `rm(list=ls())` and `gc()` in-between the two `source`s does not solve the problem I am having with RAM. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @XuWang That is a different question. See `?source` (specifically, the `local` argument).

Comment: OK. I think I was poor explainer of the issue I am experiencing. I hope that I have explained the situation better now here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792047/knitr-starting-a-fresh-r-session-to-clear-ram