# Cannot release memory with knitr

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I have an issue with `knitr` where I run can the code in the console without a problem but run out of memory when I knit the document. The markdown document is similar to

```
---
title: "xyz"
output: 
  html_document: 
    toc: true
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
author: Me
bibliography: ../ref.bib
---
```

````r
```{r setup, include = FALSE, cache = FALSE}
options(width = 100, digits = 3, scipen = 8)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  error = FALSE, cache = FALSE, 
  cache.path = "some-path-cache/", fig.path = "some-path-fig/", 
  warnings = TRUE, message = TRUE, dpi = 128, cache.lazy = FALSE)
```
````

[some code]

````r
```{r load_dat}
big_dat <- func_to_get_big_dat()
some_subset <- func_to_get_subset()
```
````

[some code where both `big_dat` and `some_subset` is used, some objects are assigned and some are subsequently removed with `rm`]

````
```{r reduce_mem}
dat_fit <- big_dat[some_subset, ]
rm(big_dat)
```
````

````r
```{r log_to_show}
sink("some-log-file")
print(gc())
print(sapply(ls(), function(x) paste0(class(get(x)), collapse = ";")))
print(sort(sapply(ls(), function(x) object.size(get(x)))))
sink()
```
````

````r
```{r some_chunk_that_requires_a_lot_of_memory, cache = 1}
...
```
````

When I knit the document using `knitr` then I run out of memory in the `some_chunk_that_requires_a_lot_of_memory` and the content of `some-log-file` is

```
            used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb)  max used (Mb)
Ncells   3220059  172    5684620  304   5684620  304
Vcells 581359200 4436 1217211123 9287 981188369 7486    
[output abbreviated (the other variables are "function"s, "character"s, and "matrix"s] 
     dat_fit          X1   some_subset     
"data.frame"   "integer"     "integer"
[output abbreviated]
     X1   some_subset     dat_fit 
5235568       5235568   591631352
```

so the objects in the `.GlobalEnv` far from sums to the 4436 MB (there are not many objects and they far smaller than 50 MB each). Running the code in the console does not yield any issues and the `print(gc())` shows a much smaller figure.

My questions are

1. **Can I do something to figure out why I use much more memory when I knit the document?** Clearly, there must be assigned some objects somewhere that takes up a lot of space. **Can I find all assigned objects and check their size?**
2. **Do you have some suggestion why `gc` release less memory when I knit the document? Is there somewhere were `knitr` assigns some object that may take up a lot of memory?**

The data set is proprietary and I have tried but failed to make small example where I can reproduce the result. As a note, I do cache some output from some chunks between `load_dat` and `reduce_mem`. I use `cache.lazy = FALSE` to avoid [this issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knitr/3mPn2neMdrk). Here is my `sessionInfo`

```r
library(knitr)
sessionInfo()
#R R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
#R Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#R Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
#R 
#R Matrix products: default
#R 
#R locale:
#R [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
#R [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
#R 
#R attached base packages:
#R [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#R 
#R other attached packages:
#R [1] knitr_1.17
#R 
#R loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#R [1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2    yaml_2.1.16
```

---

## Regarding question 1.

I also added the following to the `log_to_show` chunk to figure out if there are objects in other environments in the session that takes up a lot of space

```
# function to check if `this_env` is in `l`
is_env_in_list <- function(l, this_env){
  for(i in l)
    if(identical(i, this_env))
      return(TRUE)

  FALSE
}

# remove duplicates for environments 
remove_dup_envs <- function(objs){
  do_drop <- logical(length(objs))
  for(j in rev(seq_along(objs))){
    for(i in seq_len(j - 1L)){
      if(identical(objs[[i]], objs[[j]])){
        do_drop[j] <- TRUE
        break
      }
    }
  }
  objs[!do_drop]
}

# attempt to write function to get all unique environments 
get_env <- function(this_env = .GlobalEnv, out = NULL, only_new = FALSE){
  if(is_env_in_list(out, this_env))
    return(if(only_new) NULL else out)

  if(identical(this_env, emptyenv()))
    return(if(only_new) NULL else out)
  new. <- this_env # not emptyenv or in list so we add it

  # add parent env
  p_env <- parent.env(this_env)
  if(!is_env_in_list(out, p_env))
    new. <- c(new., get_env(p_env, out, only_new  = only_new))

  # look through assigned objects, find enviroments and add these
  objs <- lapply(ls(envir = this_env), function(x){
    o <- try(get(x, envir = this_env), silent = TRUE)
    if(inherits(o, "try-error"))
      NULL
    o
  })
  objs <- lapply(objs, function(x){
    if(is.function(x) && !is.null(environment(x)))
      return(environment(x))
    x
  })
  if(length(objs) == 0)
    return(if(only_new) new. else remove_dup_envs(c(new., out)))

  is_env <- which(sapply(objs, is.environment))
  if(length(is_env) == 0)
    return(if(only_new) new. else remove_dup_envs(c(new., out)))

  objs <- remove_dup_envs(objs[is_env])
  keep <- which(!sapply(objs, is_env_in_list, l = c(new., out)))
  if(length(keep) == 0L)
    return(if(only_new) new. else c(new., out))

  objs <- objs[keep]
  for(o in objs){
    ass_envs <- get_env(o, out = c(new., out), only_new = TRUE)
    new. <- c(new., ass_envs)
  }

  return(if(only_new) new. else remove_dup_envs(c(new., out)))
}

tmp <- get_env(asNamespace("knitr"))
names(tmp) <- sapply(tmp, environmentName)
print(tmp <- tmp[order(names(tmp))])
out <- lapply(tmp, function(x){
  o <- sapply(ls(envir = x), function(z){
    r <- try(object.size(get(z, envir = x)), silent = TRUE)
    if(inherits(r, "try-error"))
      return(0)
    r
  })
  if(length(o) == 0L)
    return(NULL)
  tail(sort(o))
})
max_val <- sapply(out, max)
keep <- which(max_val > 10^7)
out <- out[keep]
max_val <- max_val[keep]
tmp <- tmp[keep]

ord <- order(max_val)
print(tmp <- tmp[ord])
print(out <- out[ord])
```

It shows no objects that are larger than `dat_fit`.

Comment: I think you need to try harder to make a reproducible example if you want to get help.  Start with your original script, and replace the proprietary data with random data, then remove as much of the rest as you can, while still having the memory problems show up.

Comment: I do get you point. I have spend a while and it is hard to say which of the 1500 lines of code I have that cause the error. I gather though that some may be able to answer: "Clearly, there must be assigned some objects somewhere that takes up a lot of space". I.e., provide a way to find such an object in the R session.

Comment: One way to track things like this down is the following:  cut out all text.  Still got the error?  Cut out all code that doesn't calculate something shown in the chunk that gave the error.  Still got the error?  Simplify that code.  If the error goes away in one of those steps above, you've got a clue about what triggered it.  Cut out only half of what you previously cut out.  Etc.  It takes a while, but you should be able to simplify to a nice example you can show us (or you might figure it out for yourself.)

Comment: I get you point. The computation time up to the error is 14 hours so I do not have time to iteratively removing chunks and re-running everything. I am sorry.

Comment: You don't need to reproduce the original computation, just its memory footprint.

Comment: I think it is a similar issue as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12792047/5861244).