# How to release knitr cache memory in RStudio without button (with command)?

Tags: r, memory, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

Similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259676/cannot-release-memory-with-knitr).

It's a bit hard to create a MRE for this sort of thing. It happens only after working with the same RMD file for a while, say running a few chunks multiple times. Suddenly, my `rsession` process is using 13G of ram even though my data objects are nowhere near that--the bighgest maybe 1M. (`gc` shows less than 1G)

I finally realized that if I use the knitr dropdown to clear the knitr cache, it clears the `rsession` memory. But if I forget to do that frequenty, then I need to manually kill the `rsession`, hopefully not lose recent file changes, and re-run the RMD file.

Is there a way I could have a command I use periodically in the file to perform that same operation?

Alternatively, can someone help me understand how I accumulate two orders of magnitude more memory in my `rsession` than the data structures I have going in my session?

Comment: Maybe running periodically `knitr::knit_meta()` could help you.